# query execution time

Tags: postgresql

I am wondering if someone can help me understand the following query execution behavior:

I have two similar tables and table2 consists of 5000000 records.

Query: INSERT INTO table1 SELECT * FROM table2.
Execution Time: A ms.

Query: INSERT INTO table1 SELECT * FROM table2.
Execution Time: B ms.

Sometimes B >> A (B is very larger than A). Both queries are same and run twice. What could be the reason that the same query is taking very long sometime?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: i think memory issue. after first table, it just run out off memory to buffer execution. have u try switch A then B to B then A?

Comment: Are you issuing explicit BEGIN COMMIT commands after each statement?  You will want to provide explain plans at the minimum.

Comment: There are no constraints. One column is primary key and has indexing on it. I could not compare INSERT and SELECT cases. I think its not a memory issue as I rebooted the machine (to clear cache data) and run the query. However, it was taking less time. I ran the same query for around 20 times for my work and I observed this behavior (long execution time) for around 6-7 times. I am trying to regenarate the case along with EXPLAIN ANALYZE.

Comment: Also, I am not using BEGIN COMMIT commands. However, I read in PostgreSQL documentation that every command is autocommit by default.

Answer (score 1):

Can you do the test, and past all the information including the  execcution time , table ddl out ?
What's more ,you can use "explain analyze" before your statements to see if there any differentia between 
the two situation.

Comment: Here is the table definition-
CREATE TABLE staff (
    staff_id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name character varying(45) NOT NULL,
    last_name character varying(45) NOT NULL,
    address_id integer NOT NULL,
    email character varying(50),
    store_id integer NOT NULL,
    active boolean DEFAULT true NOT NULL,
    username character varying(16) NOT NULL,
    password character varying(40),
    last_update timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now() NOT NULL,
    picture bytea
);

Comment: As I posted in the above comment, I am trying to regenerate the case and I will post as soon as I get it. Last time I observed that if A is 15 minutes, then B is around 2 hrs (A = Less execution time, B = Long execution time).